# Using trigger to insert automatically from other table

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, subquery

I need to create trigger in a SQL Server database so that after the user inserts a row in the table it will automatically import the bill number from another table by bill Account in both tables and insert it in userCode column in my current table, my query is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[payTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Payment] AFTER INSERT As 
BEGIN
    update Payment
        set userCode = (
            select Bill.userCode 
            from Bill
            inner join Payment on Bill.BillAccount = Payment.BillAccount 
        )
```

The issue is: the query returns all column, how to let it import specific field regarding to userCode, when I try to insert new row, this error appears:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You say that you use MySQL database but the SQL syntax claims that you use MS SQL aka SQL Server. Adjust.

Comment: There is a lot of different `userCode` values matched the same `BillAccount` in `Bill` table. You must select one of them by some criteria - for example, you may get minimal using `select MIN(Bill.userCode)` in subquery.

Comment: @Akina thank you very much Akina, I add select MIN(Bill.userCode) but it returns one userCode for all rows , I need to returned based on BillAccount

Comment: Add proper WHERE - like `WHERE Payment.ID = INSERTED.ID`.

Comment: @Akina thank you very much , it is work , can you post your answer to flag it as answer for future users ? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a lot of different `userCode` values matched the same `BillAccount` in `Bill` table. You must select one of them by some criteria - for example, you may get minimal using `select MIN(Bill.userCode)` in subquery.
2. For to update newly inserted row only you must add `WHERE Payment.ID = INSERTED.ID` - without it all table rows will be updated.